# Python convex hull with scipy.spatial.Delaunay, how to eleminate points inside the hull?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convex-hull, delaunay

I have a list of 3D points in a np.array called `pointsList`, values are `float` :

```
[[1., 2., 10.],
 [2., 0., 1.],
 [3., 6., 9.],
 [1., 1., 1.],
 [2., 2., 2.],
 [10., 0., 10.],
 [0., 10., 5.],
... etc.
```

This code makes a Delaunay triangulation of the cloud of points:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial 

tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(pointsList) 
# Delaunay triangulation

indices = tri.simplices
# indices of vertices

vertices = points[indices]
# the vertices for each tetrahedron
```

However, before that triangulation step, I'd like to remove from my list all the points that are ***inside* of the convex hull**

A solution would be to create a new `np.array` named `shortlist`, and store them there.

But what function in `scipy` (or any other solution), will do that?

How can I program this operation?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The convex hull is a subgraph of the Delaunay triangulation.

So you might just use [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html), e. g.

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
cv = ConvexHull(pointList)

hull_points = cv.vertices
# the vertices of the convex hull

set(range(len(pointList))).difference(ch.vertices)
# the vertices inside the convex hull
```

Comparison `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` and `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` (2D)

[image]

Comment: How did you plot that image?

Comment: @TripShock It's two images. I fed matplotlib with the scatter data (scatter plot) and the data of the linked vertices (line plot). The linked vertices you can get via the indices in the `simplices` attribute.

Comment: @embert Thanks for the answer, but how can I compute the Delaunay triangulation *after* having performed the ConvexHull operation??

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com Why you want to do that? You can perform Delaunay *once* (scipy.spatial.Delaunay) and by doing so, you'll have the ConvexHull available, too (scipy.spatial.Delaunay.convex_hull).